# What is the proper term for an item in an array?

Tags: javascript, c#

I recently had a programing exam, and my teacher asked me: "What do you call the things that an array consists of?" (or something like that)
My response: "elements or items."
My teacher then asked me the same question over and over again, untill i had to give up and ask him what the proper term was.
My teacher answered: "variables."

I know what a variable is, but its not like it is only found in arrays. Am i misunderstanding his question? I had a lot of actual code to present, but he got so hung up at that one question that i didnt have much time left afterwards.

I would like to hear your thoughts on this.

(apologies, if this question does not belong on StackOverflow)

Comment: Usually it's called an "Element". Your teacher is wrong. As per the definition of `Matrix` on Wikipedia: "The numbers, symbols, or expressions in the matrix are called its entries or its elements" - the terminology for arrays was derived from the terminology for matrices.

Comment: _"In computer science, an array is a data structure consisting of a collection of elements (values or variables)... An array is stored such that the position of each element can be computed from its index tuple by a mathematical formula."_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_(data_structure) _Element_ is probably the most common term.

Comment: The terms C# uses are "variables" and "elements": _"An array is a data structure that contains a number of variables that are accessed through computed
indices ... also called the elements of the array"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure what you or your teacher would consider an authoritative answer to this, but the C# language specification [defines array elements as a sub-type of variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#921-general).

Notably, it does refer to them as array **elements**, not variables:

> C# defines eight categories of variables: static variables, instance variables, **array elements**, value parameters, input parameters, reference parameters, output parameters, and local variables.

Your teacher’s question is like asking

> which kind of big cat has a mane?

And expecting you to respond “animal” instead of “lion”.